# Is there a standalone program to get same info from gdb info symbol

Tags: debugging, gdb, elf, objdump, readelf

If I load a library in to gdb and do `info symbol 0xB0153C` I get something like `function + offset`

Is there a way to get this same information without gdb? Like some readelf/objdump option?

Thanks

Comment: `objdump --dwarf` gives you all of the debug information. But why not use gdb if it already gives you the information you need?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get this same information without gdb?

I don't know of any tool that will print function+offset.

Use `addr2line` to get the enclosing function name:

```
(gdb) info sym 0x108a
main + 10 in section .text

addr2line -fe a.out 0x108a
main
??:?
```

Or use `objdump -d` with scripting to compute the offset (here `0x108a - 0x1080`):

```
objdump -d a.out | egrep '>:| 108a:' | grep -B1 '108a:'
0000000000001080 <main>:
    108a:       48 83 ec 38             sub    $0x38,%rsp
```